# Special property of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

$A(t)$ is a symmetric matrix and for every $t$ and $s$: $A(t)A(s)=A(s)A(t)$. I want to prove that $$ A(t)e^{\int_{t_0}^t A(s)ds} =e^{\int_{t_0}^t A(s)ds} A(t)$$
I need to prove this assertion to solve one of my ODE problem!
i write seri of $e^{\int_{t_0}^t A(s)ds}$ then by using    $A(t)\int_{t_0}^t A(s)ds=\int_{t_0}^t A(t)A(s)ds$     it will prove, is it correct? How can i prove last equality by using symmetric property?

Comment: The "symmetric property" has nothing to do with the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $A(t)$ is symmetric is irrelevant for the purposes of this problem.  What you need is the following:
$$
A(t) \int_{t_0}^t A(s)\,ds = 
\int_{t_0}^t A(t) A(s)\,ds = 
\int_{t_0}^t A(s) A(t) \,ds = 
\left[\int_{t_0}^t A(s) \,ds\right] A(t)
$$ 
Because $A(t)$ commutes with $\int_{t_0}^t A(s)\,ds$, we may conclude that $A(t)$ commutes with $\exp[\int_{t_0}^t A(s)\,ds]$, as desired.

---

**Claim:** For any matrix $B$, $B \int_{t_0}^t A(s)\,ds = 
\int_{t_0}^t B A(s)\,ds$

**Proof:** (using Riemann integration) note that
$$
\int_{t_0}^tA(s)\,ds = \lim_{|\Delta| \to 0} \sum_{i} A(s_i)\Delta s_i
$$
We then note that
$$
B \sum_{i} A(s_i)\Delta s_i
 = \sum_{i} B\; A(s_i)\Delta s_i
$$
taking the limit of both sides as $|\Delta| \to 0$, we find that
$$
B\int_{t_0}^tA(s)\,ds = \int_{t_0}^tB\;A(s)\,ds
$$
as desired.

Comment: my question is :  why we can conclude your first equality?

Comment: symmetric is an extra condition in your proof

Comment: It is generally true that $B\int_a^b A(s)\,ds = \int_a^b B\;A(s)\,ds$.  One can show this using the definition of matrix multiplication, for example.  As I had meant to say originally, the fact that $A(t)$ is symmetric is irrelevant for the purposes of this problem

Comment: Another strategy of proof is to note that multiplication by $B$ distributes over the Riemann sums, so that $B$ distributes into the integral as the partition size goes to zero.

Comment: It should be noted that the common value of $A(t)e^{\int_{t_0}^t A(s)ds} $ and $e^{\int_{t_0}^t A(s)ds} A(t)$ is the derivative wrt $t$ of $e^{\int_{t_0}^t A(s)ds} $

Comment: @JeanMarie how can this point help us ?

Comment: Don't take a comment for an answer.